# merge two String array and place it into a third array in specified order

Tags: arrays, string

two string array a[]={a1,a2,a3} and b[]={b1,b2} are given.element to be inserted through user input.
then a third string array c[] to be formed such that c[]={a1,b1,a2,b2,a3};
problem to be solved using for loop(not using arraycopy)
I have tried this but it not working

```
public class ArrConcat {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String[]a=new String[3];
    String[]b=new String[2];
    System.out.println("Enter 1st array");
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        a[i]=sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Enter 2nd array");
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        b[i]=sc.nextLine();
    }

    String[]c=new String[a.length+b.length];
    for(int j=0;j<c.length;j++){
        c[j]=a[j];
        c[j+1]=b[j];

    System.out.println(c[j]);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using your logic and it created the same output I figure something out for you though.

```
int i=0;
int na=0;
int nb=0;
//these will keep track of how many elements you've used so far
while (i < c.length) {
    //check if all elements of a were moved
    if(na < a.length) {
        c[i]=a[na];
        i ++;
        na ++;
    }
    //check if elements of b have been moved
    if(nb < b.length) {
       c[i]=b[nb];
       i ++;
       nb ++;
    }
}
```

doing this you can loop over C until it is completely full, all you have to do is check if you've already moved all of one or the other. na and nb basically count how many of array a and array b have been moved already.

yours and my original code don't work because every time i is only incremented by 1 so when you add to c[i] and c[i+1] the next iteration will overwrite c[i+1] from the previous that is why we only got the first array output.

Comment: actually i am not getting right output using this logic.resultant array gives a1,a2,a3

Comment: what output do you get with your original program?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
    String[] a = new String[]{"a1","a2","a3"};
    String[] b = new String[]{"b1","b2"};
    String[]c=new String[a.length+b.length];
    int i =0;
    for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++){//Because b is shorter array.
        c[i++]=a[j];
        c[i++]=b[j];
    }
    for(int k=b.length;k<a.length;k++){// Append remaining elements present in larger array.
        c[i++]=a[k];
    }
    for(String r : c){
        System.out.println(r);
    }
```